# How can I convert from .load to .ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code example that calls .load() with the following syntax:

```
.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

Is there a simple way I can convert my call so I am using .ajax with this syntax:

```
.ajax( url [, settings] )
```

Comment: Do you know how to search on Google ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is simply [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that directly appends it's contents to the attached element.

Therefore, the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) version should be one that has a GET for it's method, or in jQuery's case, `type`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "someURL.php",
    data: {...key-value pair parameters...},
    dataType : 'html'
}).done(function(msg) {
    $('html_selector').html(msg);
});
```

`.ajax()` return [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which explains the [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) in this code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code instead of `.load` method

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',//method GET/POST
url: "url",//Your url here
data: {data},//data to be send
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
 console.log(jqXHR);
 console.log(textStatus);
 }
});
```